# How to restart a python program without task scheduler?

Tags: python, loops, web-scraping, debian, restart

I am web-scraping some data and when I finished the all websites, I want to start again this process for example with a restart code if it is exist in Python. Can I do it without Task Scheduler/Gnome on a Debian system in Python 2.7?

My code look like this:

```
.
.
.
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('LINK1')
time.sleep(5) 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "ITS A CLICK EVENT")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "ITS A CLICK EVENT AGAIN")]').click()
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
name = soup.h2.string
name2 = soup.h1.string
name3 = soup.h3.string
name4 = datetime.now()
#HERE I EXPORT THESE DATAES INTO A DATABASE

#AND HERE START MY NEW WEBSITE.
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
datatable=[]

browser.get('LINK2')
time.sleep(5) 
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "ITS A CLICK EVENT")]').click()
time.sleep(5)
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "ITS A CLICK EVENT AGAIN")]').click()
html = browser.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
table = soup.find('table', { "class" : "table table-condensed table-hover data-table m-n-t-15" })
name = soup.h2.string
name2 = soup.h1.string
name3 = soup.h3.string
name4 = datetime.now()
.
.
.
#WHAT CAN I WRITE IN THE END TO RESTART THIS ALL PROGRAM? IS THERE ANY RESTART CODE?
```

Comment: Why would you not do this with a cron?

Comment: Mmm, i already tried with a cron (i made a bash file which is "call" my python script, and i take this bash file in the cron) but it isn't working, that's why i am trying to find a new solution.